# What this means "name of an arbitrarily supplied URL parameter"?

Tags: php, mysql, security, testing

I got tested my app from the testing company.
And they gave MySQl injection vulnerabilities with filenames and message as "name of an arbitrarily supplied URL parameter".
I dont know what it means?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you used `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` for database criteria when it may have been inappropriate. If the script only performs `SELECT` queries then this is not a problem (provided the code is resistant to SQL injection attacks), but data *modification* should only be performed via POST requests.

Comment: I haven't used $_GET or $_REQUEST.In one of the file where the issues is detected i have used $type=$_FILES["file"]["type"]; and in other its $_SESSION['username'].

Comment: I have used mysql queries though.Will using mysql_real_escape_string will resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is solved by now, but here is my bit of information for this.

```
GET /contact?**1'**=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: www . mysite . com
```

A single quote was submitted in the name of an arbitrarily supplied URL parameter, and a general error message will returns.

Issue remediation

The most effective way to prevent SQL injection attacks is to use parameterized queries (also known as prepared statements) for all database access.